# VsCode quick fix add import not working in react with ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, vite

I installed VsCode new and installed react (vite + ts). I added all packages but I am not able to make the add import work with cmd + .;

[image]

But when I enter the import manual like :
[image]

then it is working,
On my old laptop was everything working fine with imports. I although have tested this with js, ts files and react and vite too.